# Creating gamemaker's gravity in c++

Tags: c++, gravity

in c++ ive been trying to recreate gamemakers gravity, so far i have this:

```
double script::lengthdir_y(double len,double dir){
        return -sin(dir* M_PI/180) * len;//Create equivalent GM lengthdir_y code.
}

double script::scr_findhsy(player* plr){
        if(plr->jumping==true)
        {
                int rpt, vspeed, y;//Make variables.
                rpt=(clock()-plr->LastMovingYUpdate)/(1000/30);
                //Check the current time, and take away the time when the player started jumping to find the time inbetween, then divide it by 1000/30 to find the ammount of GM steps.
                vspeed=plr->vspeed;//Players vspeed.
                y=plr->y;//players y.
                for(int i=0; i<rpt; i++)//Plus the lengthdir_y code to the vspeed, and plus the vspeed to the y the correct ammount of times.
                {
                        vspeed+=lengthdir_y(0.5, 270);
                        y+=vspeed;
                }
                return y;//return the new value.
        }
        else
                return plr->y;//If the player isnt falling, send the original Y value, because nothing needs to be updated.
}
```

The y value of the player doesn't get updated every step (or 33.33 milliseconds in c++) to reduce lagg, so i created this script to get the right Y value when its needed instead of every step.

But it never seems to come out properly O.O

Here some test results of debugging in the client
In these test the client sends the proper Y value, and the server sends what it thinks is the Y value of the player:

Test 1
 -Server: 384
 -Client: 384
 -Description: Standing completely still, works perfectly.
Test 2
 -Server: 373
 -Client: 349.50
 -Description: Standing completely still, works perfectly.
Test 3
 -Server: 318
 -Client: 279.50
 -Description: Standing completely still, works perfectly.

So when the player jumps, the value is meant to decrease because the Y is getting smaller, which works on both the client and the server, besides that the vaules are way off.
After the player starts falling down because of gravity, the server keeps reading "318" until the player hits the ground and the values get updated.

Comment: What *does* happen? What framework are you using? Why is your code formatted so peculiarly?

Comment: This is a part of an online game i'm making, so the code has to be the same with gamemaker 8.0, if you know nothing about it, then you probably can't help O.O

What are you talking about, the code looks fine doesn't it O.O

Comment: I guess I can't, but uh, the code looks pretty ugly. Give me a sec.

Comment: Ah, it's partly because the formatting hasn't come across to SO correctly. I'll fix it up.

Comment: what is the type of LastMovingYUpdate?

Comment: LastMovingYUpdate is a double, it holds the time, but the timing isn't the problem.

Yeah sorry, i havn't learn't c++ properly yet :)

Comment: Giving us an idea of what you expect versus what you are getting may help us give you a better answer. :-)

Comment: I updated the main post to show more infomation >.<

Comment: `rpt=(clock()-plr->LastMovingYUpdate)/(1000/30);` rpt is declared as `int` you might want to make that a `double` or it would round the value up, also adjust the numbers to `(1000.0/30.0)` as already pointed out and try.

Comment: I already adjusted the numbers and it didn't help, and its good if it rounds it up, because then i have the exact ammount of GM steps :)

Comment: If that doesn't help, my last guesses are that `vspeed` is a different unit than you guess (ie: unit/(milli)second not unit/33.33millisecond) or the player is updated outside of your script, either `jumping`, `vspeed`, `y` or `LastMovingYUpdate`. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, ill keep trying to fix it then >.<

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of integer division:

`1000/30` in this sample will equal `33` not `33.333`.

You'll need to change it to

`1000.0/30.0`

Furthermore, you save the result into an `int`, maybe `rpt` should be a `double` type.

I'll admit, I'm grasping at straws here.

Comment: GameMakers step is 33.33 Milliseconds long, so shouldn't it be right?
Well, it has 30 steps in a second, and a C++ second is 1000 steps O.O

[EDIT]
I get you now, it doesn't have the decimal places unless the division includes a decimal place :P

Still i don't think that is the problem.

Comment: This means in two seconds you'll have 61 steps versus GameMakers' 60 steps.

Comment: Ok i changed it to 1000.0/30.0, and the results are basically exactly the same as what i posted in the main post >.< Didn't help at all sorry :/